# Barcode Generation in windows 8

Tags: windows, xaml

I am trying to encode a particular string into a QR Code. I have been used Zxing lib for this.I am not able to generate the qr code using this piece of code. I have tried using Bitmap but windows 8 doesn't allow System.drawing assembly...

```
public ZXing.Rendering.PixelData  get()
        {
        string url="abcdefghijkl";
        BarcodeWriter _writer = new BarcodeWriter();



        _writer.Format = BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE;



        _writer.Options.Height = 400;
        _writer.Options.Width = 400;
        _writer.Options.Margin = 1;
            var barcodeImage = _writer.Write("tel:" + url); //tel: prefix for phone numbers
            return barcodeImage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the correct pre-built assembly for your target platform.
There is a binary for WinRT available which doesn't use the Bitmap class.
https://zxingnet.codeplex.com/releases

If you use the version for Windows Metadata (WinMD) you have to convert the
raw bytes of the PixelData to an image. It depends on the application you write
and the things you want to do.
There are sample client projects for nearly every platform available
which show you how to use the library.